With Python how can I specify which region (Location) that a Google Cloud Instance Template should be stored in?
I have a code that can create Google Cloud Compute Engine Instance Templates, but I cannot manage to make it create the instance templates regional (for example in europe-north1).

create_template
from __future__ import annotations

from google.cloud import compute_v1

from src.routes.run_fw_engagements.c_instance_template.helpers.wait_for_extended_operation import wait_for_extended_operation

def create_template(project_id: str, template_name: str, network_tags: list, startup_script: str, instance_template_region: str) -> compute_v1.InstanceTemplate:
    """
    Create a new instance template with the provided name and a specific
    instance configuration.

    Args:
        project_id: project ID or project number of the Cloud project you use.
        template_name: name of the new template to create.
        network_tags: List of network tags to apply to the instance.
        startup_script: The startup script to run on instance creation.
        instance_template_region: The location (zone or region) where the instances will be launched.

    Returns:
        InstanceTemplate object that represents the new instance template.
    """
    # The template describes the size and source image of the boot disk
    # to attach to the instance.
    disk = compute_v1.AttachedDisk()
    initialize_params = compute_v1.AttachedDiskInitializeParams()
    initialize_params.source_image = (
        "projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/family/ubuntu-2204-lts"
    )
    initialize_params.disk_size_gb = 10
    disk.initialize_params = initialize_params
    disk.auto_delete = True
    disk.boot = True

    # The template connects the instance to the default network.
    network_interface = compute_v1.NetworkInterface()
    network_interface.name = "global/networks/default"

    # The template lets the instance use an external IP address.
    access_config = compute_v1.AccessConfig()
    access_config.name = "External NAT"
    access_config.type_ = "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT"
    access_config.network_tier = "PREMIUM"
    network_interface.access_configs = [access_config]

    # Add template properties
    template = compute_v1.InstanceTemplate()
    template.name = template_name
    template.properties.disks = [disk]
    template.properties.machine_type = "e2-micro"
    template.properties.network_interfaces = [network_interface]
    template.properties.tags = compute_v1.Tags(items=network_tags)


    # Add startup script, OS Login, and location to metadata
    metadata = compute_v1.Metadata()
    metadata.items = [
        compute_v1.Items(key="startup-script", value=startup_script),
        compute_v1.Items(key="enable-oslogin", value="true"),
        compute_v1.Items(key="enable-oslogin-2fa", value="true"),
        compute_v1.Items(key="instance-template-region", value=instance_template_region)  # Add location to metadata for reference
    ]
    template.properties.metadata = metadata

    # Create client
    template_client = compute_v1.InstanceTemplatesClient()
    operation = template_client.insert(
        project=project_id, instance_template_resource=template
    )

    wait_for_extended_operation(operation, "instance template creation")

    response = template_client.get(project=project_id, instance_template=template_name)

    # Return the response or useful template info
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    startup_script = """#!/bin/bash
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install -y apache2
    systemctl start apache2
    """
    create_template(
        project_id="sindre-dev",
        template_name="template-test-10",
        network_tags=["mytag-test"],
        startup_script=startup_script,
        instance_template_region="europe-north1"
    )

wait_for_extended_operation
from __future__ import annotations

import sys
from typing import Any

from google.api_core.extended_operation import ExtendedOperation


def wait_for_extended_operation(
    operation: ExtendedOperation, verbose_name: str = "operation", timeout: int = 300
) -> Any:
    """
    Waits for the extended (long-running) operation to complete.

    If the operation is successful, it will return its result.
    If the operation ends with an error, an exception will be raised.
    If there were any warnings during the execution of the operation
    they will be printed to sys.stderr.

    Args:
        operation: a long-running operation you want to wait on.
        verbose_name: (optional) a more verbose name of the operation,
            used only during error and warning reporting.
        timeout: how long (in seconds) to wait for operation to finish.
            If None, wait indefinitely.

    Returns:
        Whatever the operation.result() returns.

    Raises:
        This method will raise the exception received from `operation.exception()`
        or RuntimeError if there is no exception set, but there is an `error_code`
        set for the `operation`.

        In case of an operation taking longer than `timeout` seconds to complete,
        a `concurrent.futures.TimeoutError` will be raised.
    """
    result = operation.result(timeout=timeout)

    if operation.error_code:
        print(
            f"Error during {verbose_name}: [Code: {operation.error_code}]: {operation.error_message}",
            file=sys.stderr,
            flush=True,
        )
        print(f"Operation ID: {operation.name}", file=sys.stderr, flush=True)
        raise operation.exception() or RuntimeError(operation.error_message)

    if operation.warnings:
        print(f"Warnings during {verbose_name}:\n", file=sys.stderr, flush=True)
        for warning in operation.warnings:
            print(f" - {warning.code}: {warning.message}", file=sys.stderr, flush=True)

    return result

How can I ensure that the instance template is created in instance_template_region="europe-north1" ?

To create a regional template instance, you need to change the client from InstanceTemplatesClient to RegionInstanceTemplatesClient.
As such, you should only need to change the part of create_template() where you create and interact with the client:
    # Create client
    template_client = compute_v1.RegionInstanceTemplatesClient() # Change client type
    operation = template_client.insert(
        project=project_id, region=region, instance_template_resource=template
    ) # Add region
    
    wait_for_extended_operation(operation, "instance template creation")

    response = template_client.get(project=project_id, region=region, instance_template=template_name) # Add region

